# Pyglet Syntax Error ("invalid syntax")

Tags: python, syntax, window, init, pyglet

So, I'm trying to create a program with the Pyglet API, and, upon running what I have written so far, I keep receiving the following error message, which is related to one of Pyglet's modules:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pyglet/window/__init__.py", line 267
    class BaseWindow(EventDispatcher, metaclass=_WindowMetaclass):
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The code I have written thus far is just a mere few lines intended to create a window:

```
import pyglet
game_window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 600)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

So far, I have not even been able to think of a solution to this problem; when I open up the **init**.py module, there isn't even a single error presented as there normally *would* be.

Plus, I've entered the error as a search query numerous times to no avail; very few seem to have stumbled upon this issue. Is anyone familiar enough with Pyglet to address this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your try to run a python3 script with python 2. Use `python3`.

Comment: Right, except that the traceback shows OP isn't on Windows, so no `.exe`.

Comment: Ahhh, OK. I didn't have the right version of Python added to PYTHONPATH. Thanks!